# What is expected behavior if I specify both left and right for spans

Tags: html, css, css-position

The following is a class for span which has `position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px;`

```
.textStyle1 {
  font-size:24px;
  font-family:'Arial';
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
}

#div1 {
 position:absolute;
 left:100px;
 top:100px;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}

#div2 {
 position:absolute;
 left:100px;
 top:100px;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 writing-mode:tb-rl;
}
```

Its used in `span`s placed inside `div`s

```
<div id="div2">
 <span class="textStyle1">Some text</span>
 <span class="textStyle1" style="left:2px; top:30px;">Another line of text</span>
</div>

<div id="div2">
 <span class="textStyle1">Some text</span>
 <span class="textStyle1" style="left:2px; top:30px;">Another line of text</span>
</div>
```

```css
.textStyle1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: Yellow;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 270px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  background-color: Cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <span class="textStyle1">Some text</span>
  <span class="textStyle1" style="left:2px; top:30px;">Another line of text</span>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <span class="textStyle1">Some text</span>
  <span class="textStyle1" style="top:2px; right:30px;">Another line of text</span>
</div>
```

Though inside elements appear appropriately, I am not clear how position is calculated when both left & right are given.
Can I assume that the other one would be ignored (based on writing mode). The question is specific to span elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect the span to consume the full width of closest parent with position:relative set.

If no parent has position:relative set the span will consume the width of the window.

Answer (score 1):

`top`and `left`have preference over `bottom` and `right` if the browser wants to be W3C compliant, as stated:

> If all three of 'left', 'width', and 'right' are 'auto': First set any 'auto' values for 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' to 0. Then,
>   if the 'direction' property of the element establishing the
>   static-position containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the static
>   position and apply rule number three below; otherwise, set 'right' to
>   the static position and apply rule number one below.
>
> If none of the three is 'auto': If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra
>   constraint that the two margins get equal values, unless this would
>   make them negative, in which case when direction of the containing
>   block is 'ltr' ('rtl'), set 'margin-left' ('margin-right') to zero and
>   solve for 'margin-right' ('margin-left'). If one of 'margin-left' or
>   'margin-right' is 'auto', solve the equation for that value. If the
>   values are over-constrained, ignore the value for 'left' (in case the
>   'direction' property of the containing block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in
>   case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve for that value.
>
> Otherwise, set 'auto' values for 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' to 0, and pick the one of the following six rules that applies.
>
> 'left' and 'width' are 'auto' and 'right' is not 'auto', then the width is shrink-to-fit. Then solve for 'left'
>   'left' and 'right' are 'auto' and 'width' is not 'auto', then if the 'direction' property of the element establishing the
>   static-position containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the static
>   position, otherwise set 'right' to the static position. Then solve for
>   'left' (if 'direction is 'rtl') or 'right' (if 'direction' is 'ltr').
>       'width' and 'right' are 'auto' and 'left' is not 'auto', then the width is shrink-to-fit . Then solve for 'right'
>       'left' is 'auto', 'width' and 'right' are not 'auto', then solve for 'left'
>       'width' is 'auto', 'left' and 'right' are not 'auto', then solve for 'width'
>       'right' is 'auto', 'left' and 'width' are not 'auto', then solve for 'right'

in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html

Answer (score 1):

You would expect a similar outcome to using `width: 100%`. Example:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .33);
}
.green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .33);
}
.blue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 266, .33);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blue">Full Size</div>
  <div class="red">Full Width</div>
  <div class="green">Full Height</div>
</div>
```